# Server.MapPath not work

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, vs-web-site-project, server.mappath

I'm developing WebSiteProject with asp.net. **Server.MapPath** method not work **but i don't get an error when upload data**.

I am checking specified folder but it's empty.

My code:

```
fupCategory.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Upload/Category/" 
                   + fupCategory.FileName));
```

Comment: Might be a permissions problem, check the logs...

Comment: what error / exception do you get ?

Comment: have you used try catch in your code???????? if yes then Try @Blachshma's Answer.

Comment: I used try catch block inside my code but i don't get exception.Specified folder has full permission.

Answer (score 0):

You're using both the `SaveAs` and `MapPath` methods correctly, it might be a problem with permissions...

Try debugging that line and see that you don't get thrown out of the method. If you're sure there is no exception thrown check the server logs...

Another option - you might be missing some of the folders in that path, but that too should raise an exception...